# does the amount of blood circulate in a body is same before and after amputation?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-physiology

if a person loose his hand in an accident do the blood flows through his body is equal to the volume of blood before accident? how human body manage with that blood which is deserved by the missed body part? if human body have such a mechanism. does it effect other body parts? or is there any change in the proportion of blood flows through different arteries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kidney regulates the amount of blood being produced and removed from/recycled in the body. Even if somehow the body lost no blood when it lost the limb, the kidneys would remove the excess blood as it filters.

I think the misconception in asking this question is that the body knows how much blood to produce for the body. Yet, that isn’t the case, it just regulates the amount based on different signals it gets from the blood.

More info: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/17630596/

Comment: Still doubt remaining. does it affect the volume of blood received by other body parts?

Comment: If you are talking about due to the arteries being severed, the blood vessels remodel themselves to make sure the body still gets enough blood. If you aren’t talking about it, the kidneys remove the excess blood until the other parts of the body receive the same amount.

Comment: okay. do you have any reference papers associated with these kind of remodeling of  arteries. if so please share the link

Comment: @DJoseph I guess I don’t specifically have an article on amputation, but here is just a general one about wound healing https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022202X15528571 and using general knowledge that it amputees do regain circulation.